# Question about Ricci Tensor

Tags: general-relativity

In a book, it says

$$R_{ik}=g^{lm}R_{limk}=R^l_{ilk}$$

$R_{ik}$ is the Ricci Tensor. It says this is formed by contraction of Riemann Tensor $R_{limk}$. So I assume the first equal sign is by definition?

How about the second equal sign? i.e. $g^{lm}R_{limk}=R^l_{ilk}$, is this a general property when the metric tensor is applied to 4-rank tensor or this is a property of the Riemann Tensor? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use the metric tensor to raise and lower the indexes of any other tensor, included the Riemann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lower and raise indices of arbitrary tensors via contraction with the metric tensor and its inverse by definition (or rather notational convention).

For non-symmetric tensors, you have to be careful about the placement of the indices, as generally
$$
R^l{}_{imk} \not= R_i{}^l{}_{mk} \not= R_{im}{}^l{}_{k} \not= R_{imk}{}^l
$$